# Simple Drawer Navigation returning null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to implement a drawer navigation for my app, but I can't even seem to get it started and I can't figure out why.  It returns a null pointer exception at the setAdapter, but I don't understand since this is copy and past almost from android and other similar tutorials.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Main Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String[] mContentTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mContentTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.contentTitles);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, mContentTitles));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

DrawerLayout.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- The main content view -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="14.5sp"
    android:paddingEnd="14.5sp"
    android:minHeight="35sp"
/>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<string name="app_name">FrontRowReady</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="home">Home</string>
<string name="settings">Settings</string>
<string name="inbox">Inbox</string>
<string name="contacts">Contacts</string>

<array name="contentTitles">
    <item>Home</item>
    <item>Inbox</item>
    <item>Contacts</item>
    <item>Settings</item>
</array>
```

error code

> 12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524): Process:  PID: 30524
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at com.maxxpotential.frontrowready.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   12-23 14:29:11.315: E/AndroidRuntime(30524):    ... 11 more

Comment: Could you put the error log?

Comment: Yep just realized that, should be up

Comment: Change the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to `setContentView(R.layout.DrawerLayout);`

Comment: perfect, how can I make that the answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20750768/2652124

Comment: I encountered similar problem. It seems it is not clear on the documentation where to place the navigation drawer layout. I placed mine in my res/layout folder. Instinctively, I though I will be declaring a NavigationDrawer through he manifest file which filters out and call the respective java file which initializes the drawer. This is intuitive for me since this must be available across all activity. I am wrong, on the tutorial, it seems  that the navigation drawer must be called on the main activity. I think this means that I have to declare and do the steps on all of my activities.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change this part of the code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

to this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.DrawerLayout);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little curious what your content view is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

What is your `R.layout.activity_main`?  Does it contain your drawer layout?  If not,

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```

Will cause mDrawerLayout to be null.

Answer (score 1):

You say your XML is called `DrawerLayout.xml`, yet you set your content as:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

You need to specify your content as the file containing the layout:

```
setContentView(R.layout.DrawerLayout);
```

Comment: This may be old but it could help me out. If you set your content view to the xml containing your drawer layout. What about the rest of your activity? Do you get all of the referencing out of the way and once you get to the section of your code with the drawer you set it to the drawer_layout.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - if you look at the xml in the question, the DrawerLayout _wraps_ the rest of the regular Activity layout xml. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: So say I have started a whole layout without a navigation drawer in mind. If I were to add it into my project it would go:  `<Drawer><MainLayoutWithEverythingINeed/><FrameLayout/><ListView/>`

Comment: Pretty much. That's all [documented in the `DrawerLayout` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html). "To use a DrawerLayout, position your primary content view as the first child with a width and height of match_parent. Add drawers as child views after the main content view and set the layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use match_parent for height with a fixed width."

Answer (score 1):

```
navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.SOME_ID);
```

Comment: Please add some comments why you post this code line.